# RabbitMQ logging connection times, queues creation times and other stats

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am wondering if Masstransit offers the option to log how long it takes for it to connect to the host, creating queues and so on.

Reasing behind this question is that Masstransit (connected to RabbitMQ) works pretty smooth locally.
When I deploy my application instead, it takes quite some time for it to connect to a cluster (which is on another serve). Therefore I would like to have some info about how expensive (in terms of time) is it to connect towards the cluster, how long does it take to create the queues it needs and so on.

I have set up the logging for MassTransit but I don't see much more than the events sent and received. So I was wondering if this option is offered somewhere that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the `DiagnosticSource` which will output those metrics.

[DiagnosticSource](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/monitoring/diagnostic-source.html)

If you have logging configured, you can look at the logs as well to see timings of those activities. Every declare and bind statement is output as the broker topology is configured.

If you're seeing slow times on a cluster, make sure you have configured enough resources for each broker instance. Most RabbitMQ performance issues are related to deploying in a wimpy docker container with insufficient memory, a single CPU, or slow disks. RabbitMQ should be treated as critical as a SQL server when it comes to resources. It's important.